# Is using Playlist.new(params[:playlist]) ever not ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, parameters

Specifically in my new/create actions. I have `@playlist = Playlist.new(params[:playlist])`. The thing is I also have sensitive data in attr_accessible that I don't want them to modify (the number of listens on a playlist, which they shouldnt be able to update).

I tried `Playlist.new(:title => params[:title], :description => params[:description], etc)` but that didn't work. I assume because I need to do `params[:playlist][:title]` but this looks quite messy. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: The whole point of attr_accessible is to restrict mass-assignment to sensitive attributes. Why did you mark them as accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Model you can write a function called for example, new_safe which creates the new object with the params you want and then returns it

like this:

```
def new_safe(params)
   playlist = Playlist.new
   playlist.title = params[:title]
   playlist.description = params[:description]
   playlist.save
   playlist
end
```

Just thinking, similiarly you could write it like this which is a bit cleaner

Controller:

```
@playlist = Playlist.new
@playlist.input_params(params)
```

Model:

```
def input_params(params)
   playlist.title = params[:title]
   playlist.description = params[:description]
   playlist.save
end
```

Comment: The `new_safe` method would have to be a class method: `def self.new_safe(params)`